# Do spring data neo4j repositories not distinguish types?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

This is a surprise. The Spring-Data-Neo4j GraphRepository code doesn't appear to be able to distinguish between objects of different types.

If I query a repository for an id which is a different type of object I would have expected it not to exist, and not be be loaded - but my test below shows that the repository doesn't appear to be qualifying the **exist**/**findOne** call with the object type and so is erroneously loading a **B** instance as if it's an **A**.

Is this a bug or a feature?

```
@NodeEntity class A { @GraphId Long id }
interface ARepository extends GraphRepository<A> {}

@NodeEntity class B { @GraphId Long id }
interface BRepository extends GraphRepository<B> {}

def "objects of different types should not leak between repositories"() {
    given: "an A and B object in the neo4j database"
    def a = new A()
    def b = new B()
    aRepository.save(a)
    bRepository.save(b)

    assert a.id != b.id

    when: "the A repository is queried for a B-id"
    def exists = aRepository.exists(b.id)
    def result = aRepository.findOne(b.id)

    then: "it should not be exist, and should not be loaded"
    !exists   // This assertion fails
    !result   // This assertion also fails
}
```

It looks like **delete** similarly can delete objects of different types. I would have thought that all CRUD method would have been qualified by the label associated with the domain object that the repository is working for.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typesafety strategy/policy in SDN for controlling that behavior:

```
<bean id="typeSafetyPolicy" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typesafety.TypeSafetyPolicy">
    <constructor-arg type="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typesafety.TypeSafetyOption"><value>RETURNS_NULL</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

or

```
@Bean TypeSafetyPolicy typeSafetyPolicy() { 
  return new TypeSafetyPolicy(TypeSafetyOption.RETURNS_NULL); 
}
```

Comment: I can't find mention of that option in the documentation. I feel that that option ought to be the default.